# kotlin коллбек, function literal with receiver

Tags: kotlin

В функцию `SharedPreferences.edit` передается коллбек `action`. Коллбек задан как `()->Unit`, то есть на вход этот коллбек ничего не принимает. Почему тогда в теле функции `SharedPreferences.edit` в коллбек `action` передается объект `editor`?

```
fun SharedPreferences.edit(
        action: SharedPreferences.Editor.()->Unit
){
    val editor = edit()
    action(editor) //Что делает эта строка?
    editor.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Коллбек задан как ()->Unit

Коллбек задан как метод-расширение класса `SharedPreferences.Editor`. Он может быть вызван как статический метод с экземпляром `SharedPreferences.Editor`, передаваемым туда первым параметром.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance

Comment: "Он может быть вызван как статический метод с экземпляром SharedPreferences.Editor, передаваемым туда первым параметром"
это сложно осмыслить. функция ведь задана со следующей сигнатурой: `(без параметров) ->без возвращаемого значения`. перед сигнатурой указан receiver, окей. это значит, что появляется возможность вызвать `receiver.function()`. но зачем давать возможность вызывать метод как `function(receiver)`? котлин ломает стереотипы

Comment: @Dmitry В .NET методы-расширения работают так же. За кадром - это статические методы.